# Open a file at the given line using the colon notation

Tags: filesystem

I'm often using `grep` to search for patterns and then opening the file with vim.

For example I've the following result in my shell:

```
interactions/BlockInteraction.js:38:                    .concat(this.prompt.postRender({}, '', renderer))
Container.js:151:        postRender : function(data, altClassName, renderer){
Container.js:156:                    return typeof elt.postRender === 'function';
Container.js:159:                    return elt.postRender(data, '', renderer);
```

What would enhance my productivity would be to be able to open a file with vim using the `path:line` pattern :

```
vim interactions/BlockInteraction.js:38
```

Is there a way to do achieve that ?

Comment: You mean: instead of opening it with vim interactions/BlockInteraction.js +38 ?

Comment: @Duikboot That doesn't generalize to opening multiple files.

Comment: `grep`, `awk` and something else for construct properly command line? Or looking/writing vim script for this task?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the relatively popular [file-line](https://github.com/bogado/file-line) plugin. Note that this plugin seems relatively unmaintained, and there exists several forks. I have a personal fork where I've made some minor updates and fixed a couple of small bugs, see [here](https://github.com/lervag/file-line).

Comment: I've just checked the network on original plugin and it seems that it's once more active. Maybe you could pull your fixes into the main repo?

Comment: I'll consider it, thanks for notifying me.

Comment: I think my fork has deviated too much, and I don't have the time to convert all of it to a well defined pull request. Thus instead I took the changes from `bogado/file-line` that seemed relevant and applied them to my fork. Works for me.